# Oracle Sequence wastes/reserves values (in INSERT SELECT)

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sequence, sql-insert

I've been struggling with sequences for a few days. I have this Origin data table called "datos" with the next columns:

```
CENTRO
CODV
TEXT
INCIDENCY
```

And a Destiny data table called "anda" with the following:

```
TIPO  = 31 (for all rows)
DESCRI = 'Site'  (for all rows)
SECU  = sequence number generated with Myseq.NEXTVAL
CENTRO
CODV
TEXT
```

The last three columns must be filled in with data from "datos" table.

When I execute my query, it all works fine, my table is filled and the sequence generates its values. But, in the INSERT INTO SELECT, I have the following conditions:
Every row in origin "datos" must not already be in the destiny "anda", so it won't be duplicated, and every row in "datos" must have the INCIDENCY flag value to 'N' or NULL.
If each row matches the conditions, it should be filled.

The thing is, that the query works fine and I have been trying with many different values. Here comes the problem:

When a row has its INCIDENCY value set to 'Y' (so it must not be copied into destiny table), it doesn't appear, but the sequence DOES consumes one value, and when I check Myseq.NEXTVAL its value is higher.

How can I prevent the sequence to add any value when it doesn't match the conditions? I've read that Oracle first reserves all the possible values returning from the SELECT query, but I can't find how to prevent it.

Here's the SQL:

```
INSERT INTO anda (TIPO, DESCRI, SECU, CENTRO, CODV, TEXT)
      SELECT(  31 TIPO,
            'Site' DESCRI,
            Myseq.NEXTVAL,
            datos.CENTRO,
            datos.CODV,
            datos.TEXT
    FROM  datos
    WHERE (CENTRO, CODV) NOT IN
            (SELECT CENTRO, CODV
              FROM   anda)
    AND (datos.INCIDENCY = 'N' OR datos.INCIDENCY IS NULL)
    )
```

Thanks in advance!!

Definition of MySeq

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE  CREATE SEQUENCE  "BBDD"."MySeq" MINVALUE 800000000000
MAXVALUE 899999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 800000000000 CACHE 20 ORDER  NOCYCLE ;
```

Comment: you will go mad if you decide to enforce no gaps in sequences.  Are you REALLY sure you need to?  Why is it a problem?

Comment: Your statement isn't valid, but without the extra parentheses I don't see gaps anyway, in 11.2.0.4. Is this what you are actually running? I know `merge` has this affect so wondering if you're really doing that. Is a trigger to set the SECU value an option? (Not that the gaps should matter, as Hugh says, and are unavoidable really)

Comment: There is **no** way you can avoid gaps in sequences. And you shouldn't worry about "wasting" numbers either. Your project will long be gone before the sequence runs out of numbers.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the definition of `MYSEQ`. Thanks.

Comment: [Quick SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5d13b2/1) showing the insert doesn't leave gaps; also shows a merge that does. If you can create a scenario that shows the behaviour you've described with just an insert, please share the whole thing. (It's academic as the gaps don't matter, but mildly interesting)

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to trick Oracle into doing this with a CTE:

```
INSERT INTO anda (TIPO, DESCRI, SECU, CENTRO, CODV, TEXT)
    WITH toinsert as (
     SELECT d.*
     FROM  datos d
     WHERE (CENTRO, CODV) NOT IN (SELECT CENTRO, CODV FROM anda) AND
           (d.INCIDENCY = 'N' OR d.INCIDENCY IS NULL)
    )
    SELECT 31 as TIPO, 'Site' as DESCRI, Myseq.NEXTVAL,
            d.CENTRO, d.CODV, d.TEXT
    FROM toinsert d;
```

I'm not quite sure if that will work.  A more guaranteed approach is to use a before insert trigger (or identity column if you are using 12c+).  You would increment the value in the trigger.

However, I do agree with Hugh Jones.  You should be confident using the sequence to add a unique value to each row and this value will be increasing.  Gaps can appear for other reasons, such as deletes.  Also, I know that SQL Server can create gaps when doing parallel inserts; I'm not sure if that also happens with Oracle.

Comment: It would be interesting to test whether using an in-line view would be sufficient to prevent view merging, when the outer query contains a reference to a sequence NextVal. If not, I suspect that the CTE would be rewritten to an inline view that would merge, and the desired effect would be lost. Possibly hints would be required to prevent view merging, or the old "rownum >= 1" trick could be employed.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you have a real problem(the gaps are not really an issue) but you can put a **before insert** (at row level) **trigger** on `anda` table and set `sequ` there with your sequence generated value.

But keep in mind that this will keep consecutive only the sequ number in a statement. You'll get gaps anyway for other reasons.

UPDATE: as Alex Poole has commented, the insert itself does not generate gaps.
See a test below:

```
> drop sequence tst_fgg_seq;
sequence TST_FGG_SEQ dropped.
> drop table tst_fgg;
table TST_FGG dropped.
> drop table tst_insert_fgg;
table TST_INSERT_FGG dropped.
> create sequence tst_fgg_seq start with 1 nocycle;
sequence TST_FGG_SEQ created.
> create table tst_fgg as select level l from dual connect by level < 11;
table TST_FGG created.
> create table tst_insert_fgg as
    select tst_fgg_seq.nextval 
    from tst_fgg
    where l between 3 and 5;
table TST_INSERT_FGG created.
> select * from tst_insert_fgg;
   NEXTVAL
----------
         1 
         2 
         3 

> insert into tst_insert_fgg 
    select tst_fgg_seq.nextval 
    from tst_fgg
    where l between 3 and 5;
3 rows inserted.
> select * from tst_insert_fgg;
   NEXTVAL
----------
         1 
         2 
         3 
         4 
         5 
         6 

 6 rows selected
```

Comment: ... as long as the OP does not hold out hope that the values will then be gap-free of course.

Comment: sure, I edited a little bit the answer to be sure will not happen. :)